# trouble following digital ocean tutorial to deploy flask app to ubbuntu 18.04 with nginx gunicorn

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn

i am trying to deploy a flask app onto aliyun ecs following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 sorry if any of these questions are stupid, i am an absolute new comer to nginx and gunicorn.

i have questions about a few steps of the tutorial.

1. the tutorial creates a sample flask project for demonstration, but i have one from a git repository. after i git clone that repository onto my server, i have an extra directory inside the "myproject" directory, which differs from the tutorial. is that ok? or will that cause problems.
2. the tutorial saids to configure flask to run with host = 0.0.0.0 so that it listens to all ips of that network, however, after i write app.run(host="0.0.0.0"), my flask app still runs with a specified host as the following image.
   [running at the server's ip instead of 0.0.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEGE9.png)
3. the tutorial instructs me to cd into the directory where app.py is located, and bind to gunicorn. and then use a browser into my server ip at port 5000. howver, i cannot load that page and it saids this site cannot be reached, [server ip] took too long to respond.
4. then i continued with the tutorial, and the after the step that told me to sudo systemctl status myproject, instead of what the expected output is, i get the expected output plus the following message tagged to the end.

[active status plug error message in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0oGy.png)

5. finally, after completing the tutorial, i receive 502 bad gateway instead of my site.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to extract the contents of your GitHub repo into the current directory use - `git clone <YOUR REPO URL> .` Look at the (.) at the end it instructs git to clone in the same directory instead of creating a new folder.
2. You can try this  - `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')`
3. Site cannot be reached because your port is blocked and you will have to enable the incoming and outgoing connections and enable the port as well (A quick google search will give you commands) (Also try to ping your server with port number and check if the port is blocked or not).
4. The systemctl thing is there to run your app every time you restart you server. Even if you don't do this and don't restart your server then the above three steps are sufficient.